# Black screen in Python Kivy label widget

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am creating a small project in Kivy/KivyMD and I have faced an issue with label widget. When I try to set really big text for the label, the label widget becomes completely black ([like in the attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOL94.png)). However, this error raises only on Apple devices, android devices work just fine. I've seen some solutions implementing scrolllabel instead of label ([text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090869/kivy-black-screen-error-in-label)), but I don't like this solution. Is there any other way to tackle this problem? I am using the dev versions of Kivy/KivyMD and the latest versions of Buildozer and Kivy-ios if it matters.

I tried to build project with different versions of Kivy-ios. Also, I tried to build different Kivy versions inside Kivy-ios, but it didnt work. I tried using scrolllabel instead, but it drastically changes the look and functionality of the widget. I am thinking of dividing text into several labels to prevent reaching the blacking limit, but I hope there is some easier way out.

```
# my implementation of Label
<LabelMod@MDLabel>:
    font_name: 'data/SEGOEUI.ttf'
    text: some_dict['humongous_txt']
```

Comment: Perhaps you are exceeding the texture size limit. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268174/text-is-not-displayed-in-scrollview-containing-only-one-label-in-kivypython-wh/77269531#77269531).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am exceeding the limit, but I wanted to know if there is any other solution than spreading text among several labels

Comment: You might try using a `TextInput` with `readonly` set to `True`.

Comment: I guess I'll try this option, thank you very much!